# Completing subcubic trees to cubic graphs

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory

A graph theory question: For given girth g, does there exist $n_0(g)$ such that any tree $T$ of even order $n \geq n_0(g)$ and maximum degree $\Delta(T) \leq 3$ can be completed to a cubic graph with girth $g$ and order $n$ (by adding $n/2 + 1$ edges)?

Answer (score 5):

Yes. First make $T$ cubic in any way. In each step, while the graph has a cycle whose length is less than $g$, pick a shortest cycle $C$ and one edge $uv$ of it. There are at most $6\cdot 2^g$ vertices whose distance is at most $g$ from $u$ or from $v$. Pick an edge $ab$ such that none of $a$ and $b$ are close to $u$ or to $v$. Delete $uv$ and $ab$ and add $ua$ and $vb$ to the graph. The length of any newly created cycle will be more than the length of $C$, so after finitely many steps this process terminates.

Comment: When picking $ab\in E(C)$ you should state that $ab\notin E(T)$ which is of course possible.

Comment: The procedure terminates with a graph whose girth is at least $g$ but how do you know the girth is exactly $g$?

Comment: Good points - I guess we can fix an edge that closes a cycle of length $g$ with $T$ (such an edge must exist), and never touch that later.

Comment: I was wondering if the additional edges can be chosen to be a cycle. Clearly it is impossible if $T$ has vertices of degree 2, but otherwise I think the same proof works if at each step we judiciously choose between adding $ua,vb$ or $ub,va$.

Comment: Yes, I think you're correct.